# How to fix syntax error at or near '1' in PostgreSQL select query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT *
FROM sales 
WHERE product_id=(
    SELECT TOP 1 product_id 
    FROM sales 
    GROUP BY product_id 
    ORDER BY COUNT(product_id) DESC
)
```

How to solve the problem that is raised near top in PostgreSQL?

I tried changing it from interger to char type but I didn't get the desired result.

Comment: `TOP 1` is not PostgreSQL valid syntax, you shall use `FETCH ROWS WITH TIES`.

Comment: Can you describe what you're attempting to do, and update your post with sample data and expected output? Maybe there's a way to solve your problem without subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `TOP 1`, use `fetch first 1 rows only` after `ORDER BY`. Like this:

```
SELECT  * FROM sales 
WHERE product_id = (
    SELECT product_id 
    FROM sales 
    GROUP BY product_id 
    ORDER BY COUNT(product_id) DESC
    fetch first 1 rows only
);
```